Python unittest mock list of coroutines
I tried to make asynhronous code and it is working fine (Python 3.12), but I struggle with tests.
Here is function that i want to test:
async def get_repositories(
    gl_client: gitlab.client.Gitlab,
    marks: vng_release_notes_obj.Marks,
    tag_pattern: re.Pattern[str],
    repositories_info: Iterable[RepositoryBasicInfo],
) -> Optional[dict[pathlib.PurePosixPath, Repository]]:

    repositories: dict[pathlib.PurePosixPath, Repository] = {}
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(4)
    tasks = [
        get_repository(semaphore, gl_client, marks, tag_pattern, repository_info)
        for repository_info in repositories_info
    ]
    for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        repository = await task

        if repository is None:
            return None

        repositories[repository.path] = repository
    return repositories

And test, there is problem:

mock properly returns (var: task) from get_repository (Coroutine[Any, Any, Repository | None]), so I can then check if it used as args in .as_completed
another problem is correctly yield from await task to return right variable (repository or None).

class TestGetRepositories(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        """Call before each test in this class."""
        self.last_modification = LastModification(
            "", datetime.datetime.now(), ""
        )
        self.gl_client = unittest.mock.AsyncMock()

        self.marks = unittest.mock.MagicMock(spec_set=Marks)

        self.tag_pattern = re.compile("dd")

        self.repository_info_a = RepositoryBasicInfo(
            "a", pathlib.PurePosixPath("a")
        )
        self.repository_info_b = RepositoryBasicInfo(
            "b", pathlib.PurePosixPath("b")
        )
        self.repository_info_c = RepositoryBasicInfo(
            "c", pathlib.PurePosixPath("c")
        )

        self.repository_info = [self.repository_info_a, self.repository_info_b, self.repository_info_c]

    class AwaitableMock(unittest.mock.AsyncMock):
        def __await__(self) -> typing.Iterator[typing.Any]:
            self.await_count += 1
            print(self.return_value)
            return iter([self.return_value.return_value])

    @unittest.mock.patch("asyncio.as_completed")
    @unittest.mock.patch("asyncio.Semaphore")
    @unittest.mock.patch("get_repository")
    async def test_invalid_case(
        self,
        mock_get_repository: unittest.mock.AsyncMock,
        mock_semaphore: unittest.mock.MagicMock,
        mock_as_completed: unittest.mock.MagicMock,
    ) -> None:
        """Test invalid case."""

        mock_semaphore_obj = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
        mock_semaphore.return_value = mock_semaphore_obj

        repository = unittest.mock.AsyncMock(spec=vng_release_notes.repository.Repository)
        repository.path = pathlib.PurePosixPath("a")

        #Here should return None in second variable
        as_compmleted_ret_a = self.AwaitableMock(return_value=repository)
        as_compmleted_ret_b = self.AwaitableMock(return_value=None)
        as_compmleted_ret_c = self.AwaitableMock()

        mock_as_completed.return_value = [as_compmleted_ret_a, as_compmleted_ret_b, as_compmleted_ret_c]
        self.assertIsNone(
            await vng_release_notes.gl.repository.get_repositories(
                self.gl_client, self.marks, self.tag_pattern, self.repository_info
            )
        )

        self.assertEqual(mock_get_repository.call_count, 3)

        self.assertEqual(len(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args), 5)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[0], mock_semaphore_obj)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[1], self.gl_client)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[2], self.marks)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[3], self.tag_pattern)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[4], self.repository_info_a)

        self.assertEqual(len(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args), 5)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[0], mock_semaphore_obj)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[1], self.gl_client)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[2], self.marks)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[3], self.tag_pattern)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[4], self.repository_info_b)

        self.assertEqual(len(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args), 5)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[0], mock_semaphore_obj)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[1], self.gl_client)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[2], self.marks)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[3], self.tag_pattern)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[4], self.repository_info_c)

        self.assertEqual(mock_semaphore.call_count, 1)
        self.assertIs(mock_semaphore.call_args[0][0], 4)

        self.assertEqual(mock_as_completed.call_count, 1)

    @unittest.mock.patch("asyncio.as_completed")
    @unittest.mock.patch("asyncio.Semaphore")
    @unittest.mock.patch(
        "get_repository", new_callable=unittest.mock.AsyncMock
    )
    async def test_valid_case(
        self,
        mock_get_repository: unittest.mock.AsyncMock,
        mock_semaphore: unittest.mock.MagicMock,
        mock_as_completed: unittest.mock.MagicMock,
    ) -> None:
        """Test valid case.

        Args:
            mock_get_repository: Mock for get_repository function.
            mock_semaphore: Mock for asyncio.Semaphore object.
            mock_as_completed: Mock for asyncio.as_completed function.
        """

        mock_semaphore_obj = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
        mock_semaphore.return_value = mock_semaphore_obj

        repository_a_path = pathlib.PurePosixPath("a")
        repository_a = unittest.mock.MagicMock(spec=vng_release_notes.repository.Repository)
        repository_a.path = repository_a_path

        repository_b_path = pathlib.PurePosixPath("b")
        repository_b = unittest.mock.MagicMock(spec=vng_release_notes.repository.Repository)
        repository_b.path = repository_b_path

        repository_c_path = pathlib.PurePosixPath("c")
        repository_c = unittest.mock.MagicMock(spec=vng_release_notes.repository.Repository)
        repository_c.path = repository_c_path

        as_compmleted_ret_a = self.AwaitableMock(side_effect=repository_a)
        as_compmleted_ret_b = self.AwaitableMock(side_effect=repository_b)
        as_compmleted_ret_c = self.AwaitableMock(side_effect=repository_c)

        mock_as_completed.return_value = [as_compmleted_ret_a, as_compmleted_ret_b, as_compmleted_ret_c]

        output = await vng_release_notes.gl.repository.get_repositories(
            self.gl_client, self.marks, self.tag_pattern, self.repository_info
        )

        if output is None:
            self.fail("Should not be None")

        self.assertIsInstance(output, dict)
        self.assertEqual(len(output), 3)

        self.assertIs(output[repository_a_path], repository_a)
        self.assertIs(output[repository_b_path], repository_b)
        self.assertIs(output[repository_c_path], repository_c)

        self.assertEqual(mock_get_repository.call_count, 3)

        self.assertEqual(len(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args), 5)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[0], mock_semaphore_obj)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[1], self.gl_client)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[2], self.marks)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[3], self.tag_pattern)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[0].args[4], self.repository_info_a)

        self.assertEqual(len(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args), 5)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[0], mock_semaphore_obj)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[1], self.gl_client)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[2], self.marks)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[3], self.tag_pattern)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args[4], self.repository_info_b)

        self.assertEqual(len(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[1].args), 5)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[0], mock_semaphore_obj)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[1], self.gl_client)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[2], self.marks)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[3], self.tag_pattern)
        self.assertIs(mock_get_repository.call_args_list[2].args[4], self.repository_info_c)

        self.assertEqual(mock_semaphore.call_count, 1)
        self.assertIs(mock_semaphore.call_args[0][0], 4)

        self.assertEqual(mock_as_completed.call_count, 1)

Thank you for your suggestions.
I checked several other questions on stackoverflow, but it did not help.

I would consider refactoring your code to avoid the need to patch get_repository, by having the caller provide a function that wraps the call to get_repository and only requires a semaphore and the list of repository information.
async def get_repositories(f, repo_info):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(4)
    tasks = [f(semaphore, x) for x in repo_info]
    for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        repo = await task
        if repo is None:
            return None
        repositories[repo.path] = repo
    return repositories

Now the thing you want to mock is just part of an argument:
get_repositories(lambda s, x: get_repository(s, gl_client, marks, tag_pattern, x), repo_info)

and can easily be replaced when you call get_repositories from your test.

Ok I figured out this, not nicest but it works.
Simplified functions:
async def func(duration: int) -> int:
    await asyncio.sleep(duration)
    return duration


async def main(data: list[int]) -> dict[int, int] | None:
    tasks = [func(i) for i in data]
    out = {}
    for i, task in enumerate(asyncio.as_completed(tasks)):
        result = await task
        if result == 2:
            return None
        out[i] = result
    return out

And the test:
class AwaitableMock(unittest.mock.AsyncMock):
    def __await__(self) -> Iterator[Any]:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(0).__await__()
        return self.side_effect


class TestGetRepositories(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    @unittest.mock.patch("asyncio.as_completed")
    @unittest.mock.patch("func")
    async def test_invalid(
        self, mock_func: unittest.mock.MagicMock, mock_as_completed: unittest.mock.MagicMock
    ) -> None:
        mock_args_0 = unittest.mock.AsyncMock()
        mock_args_1 = unittest.mock.AsyncMock()
        mock_args_2 = unittest.mock.AsyncMock()
        mock_func.side_effect = [mock_args_0, mock_args_1, mock_args_2]

        as_completed_ret_0 = AwaitableMock(side_effect=4)
        as_completed_ret_1 = AwaitableMock(side_effect=2)
        as_completed_ret_2 = AwaitableMock(side_effect=3)

        mock_as_completed.return_value = [as_completed_ret_0, as_completed_ret_1, as_completed_ret_2]
        self.assertIsNone(main([8, 4, 2]))

        self.assertEqual(await mock_as_completed.call_args[0][0][0], mock_args_0)
        self.assertEqual(await mock_as_completed.call_args[0][0][1], mock_args_1)
        self.assertEqual(await mock_as_completed.call_args[0][0][2], mock_args_2)
        self.assertEqual(mock_func.call_count, 3)
        self.assertEqual(mock_as_completed.call_count, 1)

Missing test_valid, but that is not a problem add.
